# Problems using functions on geography types with PostgreSQL - PostGIS (extension)

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, geolocation, postgis

Here is the problem,

I recently installed postgresql with postGIS extension (with functions)
I built a small database model with some geography data.

I'm actually trying to insert some geography data into it, and use functions on it... like points / polygons / ...

Problem is that when I try to use postGis functions like ST_Area, ST_Perimeter, ... PostgreSQL always returns error(s). Most of them are 42P01 meaning "unknown table" if I'm right. But tables exist...

Here is a screenshot of my actual test db :

http://s30.postimg.org/prnyyw7gh/image.png

You can see on the screenshot that the postGIS extension is active on my current model (the 1050 functions of this extension are available in this model)

I inserted data this way :

```
INSERT INTO "Base".points (point,lat,lng) VALUES ("Base".ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(45.5555 32.2222)'),'45.5555','32.2222');
and
INSERT INTO "Base".polygons (polygon) VALUES ("Base".ST_GeographyFromText('POLYGON((x y,x1 y1,x2 y2,x y))'));
```

For table Points, I have a serial field (id), a geography field (point) and 2 text fields (lat, lng). 
For table Polygons, I have a serial field (id) and a geography field (polygon).

Here are the two queries I'm tryin to make :

```
SELECT "Base".ST_Area(polygon) FROM "Base".polygons WHERE id=1
or
SELECT "Base".ST_Perimeter(polygon) FROM "Base".polygons WHERE id=1
```

These 2 tests do not work. They return error 42P01.

When tryin to test another function on my table "points", this also fails but returns a strange message. What I'm tryin is this :

```
SELECT "Base".ST_Distance((SELECT point FROM "Base".points WHERE id=1),(SELECT point FROM "Base".points WHERE id=2))
```

This function exists, but returns error message SQL state: 42883 with message :

```
ERROR : function _st_distance("Base".geography, "Base".geography, numeric, boolean) does not exist
```

I don't send any numeric or boolean... I can't explain where these errors are coming from...

I have to say that I'm new to postgresql... Problem may come from this...

Thanks for reading/Help

Comment: A couple of observations. You don't really need to store a geometry and a lat and long field, seeing as you can get the lat/lon back using ST_X, ST_Y functions, so it is redundant storage. You don't usually need to put the schema name in front of the Postgis functions like this -- I can see from your screen shot that they are installed in the "Base" schema, but if your search_path is set correctly, this is also redundant and makes the queries a bit harder to read. Same goes for the table names, unless you have multiple polygons/points tables in same db, different schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tip - post your create table statement, so we can see what the column types actually are].

I think your problems are because you are using `geography` data type rather than `geometry`; not all functions work (either at all or with the same arguments) for geography type. [Here's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-postgis-geography-and-geometry-types) an explanation of why - in short, according to the article.

> If you do a lot of measurements and e.g. have to compare sizes of
>   large polygons, it would make sense to use geography rather than
>   geometry.

To find out what arguments are expected by which functions, check the [postgis documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/). It will show you e.g.

> ﬂoat ST_Area(geometry g1);
>
> ﬂoat ST_Area(geography geog, boolean use_spheroid=true);

So you can see there are two versions of st_area. One accepts a geometry as an argument, the other accepts a geography, but you also have to add another argument.

If "polygon" is of type geography, you need

```
SELECT "Base".ST_Area(polygon, TRUE) FROM "Base".polygons WHERE id=1
-- true will measure around the geography spheroid and is more accurate
-- than false - read the documentation for what you need!
```

st_perimeter is similar.

Regarding your error on st_distance, did you see that underscore before "st_distance" in the error message? I suspect that you are running into problems because you have created the postgis extension in a schema. In PGAdmin, have a look for the function "ST_distance". You'd see that it calls in turn the function "_st_distance" - it can't find that because in your case the function is in a different schema. Try just doing this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis
```

I think that will save you a world of pain.

Lastly, I think you have the lat and lon arguments in your st_geographyfromtext the wrong way round (but I may be wrong).

Comment: The last remark is correct: the coordinate order used by PostGIS is *always* Cartesian (X Y) or (Long Lat), and *never* (Y X) or (Lat Long).

Comment: Good answer. I also encoutered the "geography-vs-geometry"-issue, when I started using postgis